# How do I access the value for this nested hash's key in Ruby?

Tags: ruby, hash

I have the following hash:

```
{:charge_payable_response=>{:return=>"700", :ns2=>"http://ws.myws.com/"}}
```

How can I get the value of the key `:return`, which in this example is 700?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have:

```
h = {:charge_payable_response=>{:return=>"700", :ns2=>"http://ws.myws.com/"}}
```

Then use:

```
h[:charge_payable_response][:return]
# => "700"
```

The colon prefix means that the key in the hash is a [**symbol**](http://ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Symbol.html), a special sort of unique identifier:

> Symbol objects represent names and some strings inside the Ruby interpreter. They are generated using the :name and :"string" literals syntax, and by the various to_sym methods. The same Symbol object will be created for a given name or string for the duration of a program‘s execution, regardless of the context or meaning of that name. Thus if Fred is a constant in one context, a method in another, and a class in a third, the Symbol :Fred will be the same object in all three contexts.

Answer (score 2):

If:

```
data = { :charge_payable_response=> { :return=>"700", :ns2=>"http://ws.myws.com/" } }
```

Then to get the return value use:

```
data[:charge_payable_response][:return]
```

Answer (score 0):

I would say it should be:

```
hash[charge_payable_response][return]
```

But, isn't `return` a reserved word in Ruby? That could cause a problem.

Comment: Hi Peter,

Thanks for the quick reply, I wrote it like this
puts hash[:charge_payable_response][:ns2]

then it works without a problem but, it is giving 0 as the return all the time..

any idea what that it

cheers,

sameera

Comment: This won't work; `charge_payable_response` will be parsed as a method call.